# Crystal Reports if function combined with a val function

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I feel very stupid but I cannot see what is going on.

The field `U22` has a varchar field. So i'm doing the following in term of logic

If U22 IS NULL OR empty then take the numbers out of {ENTREPRISES.U22}

```
IF ISNULL({ENTREPRISES.U22}) OR {ENTREPRISES.U22} = '' THEN '' 
 ELSE VAL({ENTREPRISES.U22})
```

Everytime I'm saving this , I have this error

[image]

> Type a string

I've done the following

If I only put this `VAL({ENTREPRISES.U22}`, things are fine, if I put the other part `IF ISNULL({ENTREPRISES.U22}) OR {ENTREPRISES.U22} = '' THEN ''` things are fine too.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot mix data types in an If Then Statement .. try this

```
IF ISNULL({ENTREPRISES.U22}) OR {ENTREPRISES.U22} = '' THEN '' 
 ELSE {ENTREPRISES.U22}
```

or

```
IF ISNULL({ENTREPRISES.U22}) OR {ENTREPRISES.U22} = '' THEN 0 
 ELSE VAL({ENTREPRISES.U22})
```